# asp.net c# add html to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a dropdownlist in my webform that contains several items (language select). I want to add a countryflag before the listitem text but asp.net doesn't render html in a dropdownlist. What is the best way to do so? The listitem value must be retained. The country flag is just an image...

I'm using a jquery attempt now but it doens't work.

ASP:

```
<asp:DropDownList
      id="ddlLanguage"
      runat="server"             
      DataTextField="Value"
      DataValueField="Text"
      AutoPostBack="true">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code-behind:

```
ListItem langListEN = new ListItem("EN");
langListEN.Attributes.Add("id", "idEN");
ddlLanguage.Items.Add(langListEN);
```

jQuery

```
var flagEN = $('#ddlLanguage option#idEN');
flagEN.prepend( "<img src='../assets/images/country/gb.png' />" );
```

Comment: The basic `select` element doesn't support HTML.  You'd need to either use a plugin or manually build a component which mimics the behavior of a `select` but is created using HTML elements.

Comment: try this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9f0ae2/Asp-Net-bind-dropdownlist-with-images/